Manually verifying RSA signature in SAML response
I've been trying to verify a signature of a SAML Response after finding that .NET's SignedXml has an issue (where the exact same SAML Response can be verified using Java).
I know why this is, which has lead me to wanting to verify the signature myself, which shouldn't be too difficult. In theory.
The long-and-short of it is I have some fairly vanilla RSA signature code, and using an external tool to calculate the expected digest of the SignedInfo element to compare to.
The code below truncates the signature and modulus for readability. But I've tested and proven on other calculations that the Big-Endian -> Little-Endian conversion and un-signing the resulting number works as I would have expected.
    var sigString = "Xxfh0hq34DGIQibeBrNcYuU/XD0aX...IviQm/5jZK6pD9wReldSPoo=";
    var sigBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sigString).Reverse().Append<byte>(0x0).ToArray();
    var s = new BigInteger(sigBytes);

    var modulusString = "lg4dkGLwfAApoNtWoX...oxvjjaGfH9PzoE=";
    var modulusBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(modulusString).Reverse().Append<byte>(0x0).ToArray();
    var n = new BigInteger(modulusBytes);

    var exponentString = "AQAB";
    var exponentBytes =  Convert.FromBase64String(exponentString).Reverse().Append<byte>(0x0).ToArray();
    var e = new BigInteger(exponentBytes);

    var r = BigInteger.ModPow(s, e, n);

    var expectedB64 = "XeHIN99Mkt5A/HswHotEndGJ6ahw/0l8jbjy92Fjsaw=";
    var expected = new BigInteger(Convert.FromBase64String(expectedB64).Reverse().Append<byte>(0x0).ToArray());

    var expectedHex = expected.ToString("X");
    var resultHex = r.ToString("X");
    
    //Removing pkcs1.5 padding
    var actualHex = resultString.Substring(resultString.Length - expectedString.Length);


    Debug.Assert(resultHex == actualHex); //Fail


What is the issue you identified with SignedXml? You definitely shouldn’t roll your own crypto.

Like really really really not roll your own, it's the path to the dark side. Even the experts can screw up https://heartbleed.com/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(security_vulnerability) Perhaps you can reimplement parts of SignedXml using the source https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography.Xml/src/System/Security/Cryptography/Xml/SignedXml.cs and workaround the issue. Maybe even file a bug report on the repo there.

Well, the good news is that I'm not the kind of idiot to want to completely re-do the security, because you're of course completely right that I could (and very likely would) get aspects of the crypto wrong.
But the issue I have is a well-documented interop issue that I attempted to get some help with on SO, but the post got no traction.
The issue with SignedXml is that it canonicalizes the XML incorrectly and that leads to signature validation failures.
